# Small executable hangs when invoked from Sublime plugin via Popen

Tags: python, gtk, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

Ok so the problem has a few parts i must describe first, then the question.
I wrote a Sublime Text 2 plugin to open a new file from the text selection of the system. The command should open the file from the selected text even if the text is selected in terminal - yes it's Nedit's Ctrl+Y function.
For this purpose i wrote a plugin for Sublime (my code is in a secure environment so I can only reproduce the relevant pieces here - excuse typos)

```
class OpenNamedFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        cmd = ['/home/razvan/clip.exe']
        popen_arg_list = {"shell": False,
                          "stdout":subprocess.PIPE,
                          "stdin":subprocess.PIPE}
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **popen_arg_list)
        selection = proc.communicate()[0]
        print selection #for debug puposes i just print the text in the sublime console
```

The other piece of code is clip.exe, a small gtk app written in C (simplified version below - i used glib.h, gtk.h and string.h)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    GtkClipboard *clipboard;
    gchar *clipboard_text;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    clipboard = gtk_clipboard_get(GDK_SELECTION_PRIMARY);
    clipboard_text = gtk_clipboard_wait_for_text(clipboard);
    puts(clipboard_text);
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

1. Select text in terminal, go to Sublime and invoke command -> selected text is displayed ok to Sublime console
2. Un-select text in terminal and go to Sublime and invoke command -> last selection is displayed ok
3. Select text in Sublime and invoke Sublime command -> selected text is displayed ok
4. Select text in either Sublime or terminal and call clip.exe executable in linux terminal -> selected text is displayed ok in terminal
5. Select text in Sublime, un-select text in Sublime and call in terminal clip.exe -> last seletion is displayed ok
6. **And now the PROBLEM**: Select text in Sublime, un-select text in Sublime and invoke Sublime command -> Sublime hangs for approx 30 seconds and outputs an empty string afterwards

I tried:

1. Debugging with prints -> the hang seems to happen when communicate() is called but the output of the prints is all written at once after Sublime un-freezes so it's useless ( i mean prints all over run function all get dumped in the end in one go no matter where i place them)
2. Tried setting an alarm after 1 sec using signal.alarm and sending kill() to the proc handler -> still freezes

Thoughts?
Thanks in advance for reading this novel :)